How could this code have a runtime error?
this is the code I submitted as a solution to the problem 996A on CodeForces:
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    int n; cin >> n;
    int *dp = new int[n+1];
    int cs[] = {100, 20, 10, 5, 1};
    dp[0] = 0;
    dp[1] = 1;
    //if(n % 100 == 0){
    //  cout << n/100;
    //  return 0;
    //}
    for(int i = 2; i<=n; i++){
        dp[i] = dp[i-1]+1;
        for(int c : cs){
            if(i >= c) {
                dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i-c]+1);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << dp[n];
}

And it always says "Runtiume Error on test 3", although it works fine for me.

How large is n?

On using <bits/stdc++.h>: please don't

Please bother to share details of test 3.

Please explain what this code is supposed to be doing.

The first two lines of the main function are useless. Use proper header files. Learn about std::vector. And learn the basics of C++ properly before going to any site that does any kind of "competition" or "judging".

"How could this code have a runtime error?" -- This barely narrows down your question from "I have a problem". See [ask] for advice on writing question titles.

As for any kind of "runtime error", create a [mre] with the input hard-coded, and debug your program locally on your own system.

Find another method - CodeForces problem 996A says 256MB memory limit and you've gone way over that for n=1e9

In order to give the guy his billion dollars, the poot bank teller will have to draw a table with a billion entries and spend an entire human lifetime filling it...

Questions should be self contained, you should explain what the code is supposed to do, what the input is and the expected and actual output

If it's this problem, you are over thinking it. Hint n / 100 = # of 100s (integer division), and n % 100 = remaining amount. Repeat with remaining amount for other denominations, highest to lowest.

Did you ask this question on the CodeForces forums?  If not, why not?  If you did, could you please link to that discussion, so we can read the responses.  Thanks!

@lastchance answered it. OP, in this situation you need to post the input or at least link to the problem - especially since CF problem numbering isn't intuitive.

This shows you've not been learning C++ before you started competitive coding int *dp = new int[n+1];, in C++ we use std::vector<int> dp(n+1);  for this.  My advice is really to spent time learning C++ itself first (e.g. learncpp.com)

See also What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?
